# How to define Class object to define gpiozero functions

Tags: python

using gpiozero - I control devices as LED's, Buttons, Relays etc.
to define a device as LED, for example :
`led1=gpiozerp.LED(17)` ,while `17` is gpio pin#.

and then to control it ( "On" or "off" ) :
`led1.on()`

I want the code to allow the user to choose if `dev1` is LED, or Button and not predetermind it, and the code will use `dev1.on()` no matter what device it is.

I tought using class for it as:

```
class devices(object)
  def __init__(self, name, hdware,pin,state)
    self.name=name
    self.hdware=gpiozer.hdware(pin)
    self.state=state
```

but it does not work.

Comment: What does *"it does not work"* mean? Do you get errors, wrong results, what do you see when debugging, ...

Comment: Why would you like to set the value for a button from within?

Comment: I'm guessing I did not define class oject as needed. it it even possible ?

Comment: @JohanL -I wish to control dev1 without predetermine weather it is a LED or a switch - so the syntax should be `dev1.on()'